# How to refactor a return of the same value in both catch and try?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I've been noted by Sonar that this is a smelly code. How could I fix it?

```
invokeFieldAccessor(property.getField(), this.instance, theValue,
    new FieldAccessorHandler() {
        @Override
        public synchronized Object accessField(
                final Field field, final Object objectInstance,
                final Object value) {
            try {
                field.set(objectInstance, value);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
```

EDIT: The desired output is to **return null** with or without exception

Comment: With your code, you return null even if no exception occurs. Is it the desired behaviour?

Comment: Yes. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the return from the `catch`:

```
        try {
          // ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
          // Fall through to the return afterwards...
        }
        return null;
```

But I suggest that it is a very bad idea to do *nothing* with the `Exception`.

It's not advisable to catch `Exception`, either: you should probably be catching `ReflectiveOperationException`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `finally` to do so.

```
try {
...
}
catch {
...
}
finally {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: No. Don't return from `finally`. Just return after the `try/catch`.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning null regardless of the outcome of the try/catch block. What makes this "smelly" is that there's a return null in the catch block, whereas the try block doesn't have any.

It's probable that there's a bug here.

```
new FieldAccessorHandler() {
    @Override
    public synchronized Object accessField(
            final Field field, final Object objectInstance,
            final Object value) {
        try {
            field.set(objectInstance, value);

            //Why is nothing being returned here?
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

From what is visible in this code, this method should be a void method. It's setting a value, not reading one, which is why you're returning null by default anyway.

So it's likely that you're implementing the wrong interface, or, if you have to return a value, send `null` only after the try/catch:

```
new FieldAccessorHandler() {
    @Override
    public synchronized Object accessField(
            final Field field, final Object objectInstance,
            final Object value) {
        try {
            field.set(objectInstance, value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           logger.error(e); //log the exception
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the catch clause you should log the exception or rethrow it. Your implementation just hides it. And besides that, returning null value is not the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
invokeFieldAccessor(property.getField(), this.instance, theValue,
    new FieldAccessorHandler() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void accessField(
                final Field field, final Object objectInstance,
                final Object value) {
            try {
                field.set(objectInstance, value);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```